# Como puedo seleccionar los ultimos 3 ID desde SQL con PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

Estoy creando una especie de portal con noticias el cual esta dividido y el contenedor, que es donde se almacenan las noticias y se muestran las ultimas 3 tengo este código, el cual me muestra desde el id 3 al 1 pero yo busco que se vean solo los últimos 3, ¿me explico?.

A continuación muestro el código que tengo:

**home_contenedor.php**

```
<?php
include_once('includes/conectar.php');
    $link=conectar();
?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php
                $total=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl_noticias_blog"); 
                for($total=3; $total > 0  ; $total--){
                    $obtenertitulo=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from tbl_noticias_blog order By id='$total' DESC");
                    $titulo=mysqli_fetch_array($obtenertitulo);
                        $dc=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from tblnoticias_blog where titulo='$titulo[titulo]' Order By id DESC");                  
                            ?>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h2>
                        <?php echo $titulo['titulo']; ?>
                    </h2>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo utf8_encode($titulo['descor']); ?>. </p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">Ver detalles &raquo;</a></p>
                </div>
                <?php   
                    }
            ?>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
```

[image: Base de datos y lo que muestra la pagina.]

Con la consulta de **Kevin** lo que muestra el código es esto:
[image: 3 Veces el Ultimo ID]

**Se soluciono de la siguiente manera:**

```
<?php
include_once('includes/conectar.php');
    $link=conectar();
?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php
                        $dc=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from tbl_noticias_blog where estatus='importante' Order By id DESC limit 3");         
                            while($titulo=mysqli_fetch_array($dc)){   
            ?>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h2>
                        <?php echo $titulo['titulo']; ?>
                    </h2>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo utf8_encode($titulo['descor']); ?>. </p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">Ver detalles &raquo;</a></p>
                </div>
                <?php   
                            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hola 720TA, puedes mostrar el codigo generado en la web, y no el `php`? Un saludo

Comment: Me muestra las noticias con los id 3, 2 y 1 lo muestro con una foto.

Comment: que quieres hacer un sql con los ultimos tres? quieres filtrarlo por PHP ? no comprendo tu pregunta , te recomiendo colocar lo que quieres que salga en la respuesta

Comment: Quiero que se vean las ultimas noticias, por ende los últimos 3 ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según entiendo la consulta que te podria servir es la siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM tblnoticias_blog ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 3
```

En la cual seleccionamos todo de la tabla y lo ordenamos de manera descendente con un máximo de tres registros que en este caso serian los últimos tres.

**Edito**
De esta manera la puedes implementar.

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
    $obtenertitulo=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM tblnoticias_blog ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 3");
    while ($titulo=mysqli_fetch_assoc($obtenertitulo)) {                   
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>
                <?php echo $titulo['titulo']; ?>
            </h2>
            <p>
                <?php echo utf8_encode($titulo['descor']); ?>. </p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">Ver detalles &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <?php   
    } 
    ?>
</div>
```

espere que te sirva

Comment: El problema es que cuando lo hago de esa manera, solo me muestra 3 veces el ultimo ID, no los últimos 3

Comment: Eso es raro, esta consulta trae los últimos tres registros y no seria necesario el ciclo que estas utilizando para traer los registros

Comment: Kevin, yo creo que el problema es cuando haces una consulta, esta por defecto te muestra los 3 últimos registros pero no es posible ya que necesito llenar div con esa información por eso ocupo un for para hacer el proceso 3 veces y de esa manera crear 3 div, cada ciclo que se cumple crea un div con un titulo, una pequeña descripción y un botón.

Comment: edite mi respuesta con lo que deverias modificar